# shell_exec in PHP returns empty string

Tags: php, shell-exec

`shell_exec` and `exec` are not returning any content. I can't figure out what's wrong.

Here's some code:

```
echo 'test: ';
$output = shell_exec('whoami');
var_export($output, TRUE);
echo PHP_EOL . '<br>' . PHP_EOL;
```

And here's the source of the output

```
test 2: 
<br>
```

I do not have control over the host, but I believe they're running SuPHP. According to `phpinfo`, safe_mode is off. Running `whoami` from SSH outputs the expected value.

I'm at a loss. Any idea how to debug this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're never printing the `$output` variable. The `var_export()` call *returns* the content of the variable when you call it with a `true` second parameter, it does not print it directly.

Comment: I changed it to `echo var_export($output, TRUE);`. Now it outputs `NULL`. Any ideas?

Comment: @sharoz Try `shell_exec('/usr/bin/whoami');` instead, and make sure /usr/bin is the correct path.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the output from a shell command read back into PHP, you're probably going to need `popen()`.  For example:

```
if( ($fp = popen("some shell command", "r")) ) {
    while( !feof($fp) ) {
        echo fread($fp, 1024);
        flush(); // input will be buffered
    }
    fclose($fp);
}
```